# Find the sum of series$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the sum of series$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$

Here the General Term $U_r$=$\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}$

I tried to express this in the form $U_r=$$V_r$ - $V_{r-1}$. I have an idea that the denominator of $V_r$ should be $(r+1)(r+2)$. Can you please give me a hint to find an appropriate 'Numerator'? Thanks!

Comment: I learnt from Wolfram alpha that the answer for the above is $\frac{n(3n+1)}{4(n^2+3n+2)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG $V_n=\dfrac{an+b}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary constants

$$\dfrac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\dfrac{ar+b}{...}-\dfrac{a(r-1)+b}{...}$$

$\implies2r-1=r(ar+b)-(r+2)(a(r-1)+b)$

Compare the constants & the coefficients of $r$ to find $a,b$

Answer (score 5):

Note that, for every $r$,
$$\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{2r-\frac12}{r(r+1)}-\frac{2(r+1)-\frac12}{(r+1)(r+2)}$$
hence, using the well-known trick that $$\sum_{r=1}^n(a_r-a_{r+1})=a_1-a_{n+1}$$ one gets $$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\left.\frac{2r-\frac12}{r(r+1)}\right|_{r=1}-\left.\frac{2r-\frac12}{r(r+1)}\right|_{r=n+1}$$ that is,
$$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac34-\frac{2n+\frac32}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$ or, equivalently, $$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{n(3n+1)}{4(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $$
\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{\frac52r -\frac12(r+2)}{r(r+1)(r+2)}=\frac{\frac52}{(r+1)(r+2)}-\frac{\frac12}{r(r+1)}.
$$

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Nice work..

Comment: Sorry but how do you suggest to use this to compute the sum in the question?

Comment: @emil Sorry but how do you plan to use this to compute the sum in the question?

Comment: @upvoters Sorry but how does this help to compute the sum in the question?

Comment: @Did It certainly does not fit OP's requirement that $U_r = V_r - V_{r-1}$, but I think it can be used in this way:$$\sum_{r=1}^n U_r = \frac52 \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{(r+1)(r+2)}-\frac12\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r(r+1)} =\frac52 \left(\frac 12-\frac1{n+2}\right) -\frac12\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right).$$ Or, I've just realized that it can be made into$$\left(\frac52\frac{1}{r}-\frac12\frac{1}{r+1}\right)-\left(\frac52\frac{1}{r+1}-\frac12\frac{1}{r+2}\right).$$

Comment: Thus: (at least) incomplete answer. (But at least you addressed my comments, something that neither the OP nor the anonymous upvoters saw fit to do.)

Answer (score 2):

Use partial fraction decomposition to get that:

$$\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)} = \frac{3}{r+1} - \frac{5}{2(r+2)} - \frac{1}{2r}$$

Then you can see that a lot of the terms cancel out. For example the first term for $r=2$, the middle term for $r=1$ and the last term for $r=3$ cancel out. Thus you would get that

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)} = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{n+1} - \frac{5}{2(n+1)} - \frac{5}{2(n+2)}$$